# Check if ABMultiValueRef is has no values

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, abaddressbooksource

I want to check if a contact in my user's addressbook a phone number has. If he does, I want to display that name in an UITableView

I've tried to check for `phoneNumbers != nil`, but that doesn't work. This is my entire code:

```
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

if(phoneNumbers != nil){
  [_numbers addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", phoneNumbers]];
}
```

Comment: So, what is phoneNumbers value when the ABRecord doesn't have a phone property? Can't you just check against that value as opposed to nil?

Comment: Not really, when I log it it says ABMultiValueRef 0x10ab8bf40 with 0 value(s)\n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ABMultiValueGetCount` to check if phoneNumbers has any values in it.

example based on question:

```
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

if(ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers)){
    [_numbers addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", phoneNumbers]];
}
```