# Application is Crashing when no phone number is present

Tags: ios, swift

Here is a better example:

```
let person: ABRecordRef = ABPersonCreate().takeRetainedValue()

let phoneNos = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()

if ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNos) > 0 {
    print("yay") } else {
    print("nay") //you will never see this }
```

Always crashes.

```
let person: ABRecordRef = ABPersonCreate().takeRetainedValue()
//lets add a number then
let phoneNumbers: ABMutableMultiValue =
ABMultiValueCreateMutable(ABPropertyType(kABMultiStringPropertyType)).takeRetainedValue()
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, "1234", kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, nil)
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumbers, nil)

let phoneNos = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()

if ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNos) > 0 {

    print("yay")
} else {
    print("nay") //you will never see this
}
```

Works just fine. 
I need to check if there is a phone number, how the #$^% am I supposed to do that when ABRecordCopyValue can't return a nil without exploding.

Comment: Have you tried this: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534436/check-if-abmultivalueref-is-has-no-values` ?

Comment: I sure did.  I couldn't see how it applied. They were crashing on no contact found instead of no number for contact so they copied it to an array to get the number of people.  If I even touch `ABRecordCopyValue` with `kABPersonPhoneProperty` returning nil it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will prevent the crash, if `ABRecordCopyValue` returns `nil`; but in case there will be a value returned, it will be stored in `phoneNos`:

```
if let phoneNos = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty)?.takeRetainedValue()
{
     print("\(person)'s phone number: \(phoneNos)")
}
else
{
     print("nay")
}
```